# MS Access and SQL Server Connection (Trusted Source vs Passing Login Credentials)

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc, windows-authentication

I currently have an Access database that is split and has about 80 or so registered users.  We are  now migrating the back end to SQL server. I work for a very large entity that has established IT policies so making some changes on the SQL server side could take a while due to approvals needed.  Having said that we are looking for a way maybe to do this on the Access front end so we don't have to change anything in SQL server but I have not figured a way yet.  So here is what I am trying to do..

I need the Access front end to connect to SQL server using a service account (A separate windows account set up just for this database).  I can get into the SQL server with my personal account using VBA connection strings in Access that use the Trusted Source option.  If I log into windows using the service account I can also use VBA to connect to SQL Server using the trusted source.  It is worth noting that the SQL server account authentication is set to use Windows authentication, not SQL Server authentication.  However, If I try to connect to SQL Server with VBA by passing username and password credentials (without using a trusted source) it is always denied. I am assuming if the SQL Server was set to SQL Server authentication it would allow me to send the username and password but because it is set to Windows authentication it will not accept anything other than my current Windows account.

So essentially my questions are:

1. Can I pass a username and password to SQL Server through MS Access and gain access if the SQL Server account is set to use Windows Authentication instead of SQL Server authentication.  Or is the only way to access this SQL account to use a trusted source.
2. And if I can only use a trusted source, is there any way that you could see that I could have my 80 users gain access to SQL server through the one Windows service account while logged onto their own Windows account?

Thank you.

Comment: Basically, no...  If the SQL Server instance is set to only use Windows authentication then for an Access front end you're pretty much relegated to adding the users on the SQL Server side.  Otherwise you have to put a middle tier in place and play some serious games with that.

Comment: Is there anything that can be done on the SQL Server side to make this work other than switch the authentication type from windows auth to SQL server auth?

Answer (score 1):

if using windows auth, then sql server rights and settings are controlled by your domain server and their logons. You don't have to do anything at all, except ensure that each user has rights to the database. In other words active dir is where you will set each users rights. You can't impersonate another user logon (like say you can in IIS services). So you assign tables rights etc. in the active domain (windows auth) logon system. You don't have to do anything access side. If using sql logons, and you can do this without having to re-link tables and rights are sql server assigned and based

The whole idea of using windows auth is that you don't want nor need the hassile of having to worry about some single application and user rights. So you set what they can see on sql server via active domain controller (windows auth logons). So there is no need to have users logon or off sql server, since the fact that they could logon into their workstation is how rights are controlled. So, if a particular user is not to be give rights to the sql server, then you set and control that with the domain controls and active directory.

o, of course in practice, one would not give rights to each user, but of course some type of security group (like full time employee) would be given the rights, and thus all 80 users who are members of that group would have rights. or maybe there is a salesgroup, or planning security group. So you ONLY have to (and only should) assign rights to a security group, and not individual users, since that takes too much effort for the system administrators.

So, which users have rights to the database will now be controlled by active directory, and the so called domain controller.  It would not make sense if you could impersonate other users on the system, since then little security would exist on such a system if you can just "become" any old user and logon on your system.

So, you don't have to do anything here, but just ensure that rights are given to each users logon, and they will then have rights to use sql server.

As noted, in practice such rights are typical granted to a security group, and its too much work to try and manage this on a per user basis.